# How to migrate AES mode from one to another?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have 2 functions: encrypt/decrypt implemented by AES

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend                                                      
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes

DEFAULT_MODE = modes.ECB()

def encrypt(data, key):
    encryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), DEFAULT_MODE, backend=default_backend()).encryptor()
    return encryptor.update(data) + encryptor.finalize()    

def decrypt(data, key):
    if len(data) == 0 or len(data)%16 != 0:
        raise ValueError
    decryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), DEFAULT_MODE, backend=default_backend()).decryptor()
    return decryptor.update(data)
```

The code can be executed in below:

```
>>> encrypt(b'a'*16, b'I_got_one_key_in_32bytes_length.')
'\xab\x07\x9d\xa0\xf0\xa0g\x9ae\xd9\x10\x9e\xea2\xb4\x17'
>>> decrypt(b'\xab\x07\x9d\xa0\xf0\xa0g\x9ae\xd9\x10\x9e\xea2\xb4\x17', b'I_got_one_key_in_32bytes_length.')
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

---

The mission here is to `change the mode` from ECB to others, say GCM.

```
DEFAULT_MODE = modes.GCM('iv')
```

The code can still be executed in below:

```
>>> encrypt(b'a'*16, b'I_got_one_key_in_32bytes_length.')
'Y5y\xbe\xeeK\xb9\x10\xcdf\x99\xa6\x1d\xf2\xa0\x1e'
>>> decrypt(b'Y5y\xbe\xeeK\xb9\x10\xcdf\x99\xa6\x1d\xf2\xa0\x1e', b'I_got_one_key_in_32bytes_length.')
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

However, since those encrypt/decrypt function have been used broadly for a while, an issue is raised: **How to migrate to new mode without impacting original encrypted data?**

---

PS: my draft thought is logic like below: decrypting data in GCM mode if possible, otherwise decrypting in ECB mode; and encrypting all of them in GCM mode later. But AFAIK, this idea won't work since I have no way to raise the Error. **With this approach, is that possible to know the AES mode of encrypted data?**

```
def decrypt(data, key):
    try:
        # decrypt data by key in GCM
    except GCMDecryptFailedError:
        # decrypt data by key in ECB
    return decrypted_data
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I have no way to raise the error"?  This would be the case for ECB mode, but GCM mode decryption can actually fail (because the tag won't match).  I think the approach you've outlined will work fine!

Comment: @Luke Joshua Park Thanks, that's a good confirmation from experienced people. I tried a bit and it worked. My old encrypt function needs to return a tag and decrypt function needs a new tag arguments. You can reply this question in below (perhaps more details for other modes without tag or similar identifier). Although it seems an extreme easy domain knowledge for you, but you did solve my problem.

Comment: Add a version eye-catcher to your encrypted data.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen What's an eye catcher? Should I equate that with "large magic value" as I've specified in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is to use a cryptographic algorithm directly, without specifying a specific protocol, and a protocol version number that comes with that. Fortunately, there are ways of getting out of this, and *specify a specific protocol*.

One of the tricks employed by cryptography is that it is impossible to generate specific content randomly simply because the chance of generating the a specific value reduces by each bit. So what you can do is to prefix your ciphertext with e.g. a 128 / 16 byte bit value. The chance that you generate this value at the start of your ciphertext is 2 to the power of 128 for each message (less if the messages are not random themselves for a specific key). In other words, the chance is as low as guessing an AES-128 key; we call such a chance "negligible". This trick of course depends on the output of ECB encryption using a random key to be random as well.

However, for the future you might want to include one or more bytes as *protocol version indicator*. So you could send e.g. the byte value `01` as new version, and then the 16 byte *magic value*, followed by the random nonce for GCM, the ciphertext and the GCM authentication tag (if that's not already included in the GCM ciphertext). Once you got rid of the ECB version of your protocol (version `00` not indicated in your messages) then you can get rid of the magic and re-purpose the 16 bytes in the protocol header of your messages, for protocol 2 or higher.

If you want to generate a nice magic then you could use any kind of 16 byte string, say `"Protocol 1, GCM:"` (without the quotes) in ASCII. You could also use the leftmost 128 bits of a hash if you want to use a larger string.

So initially your logic would be, in pseudo-code:

```
versionByte = message[0]
if message.length >= 17 && versionByte == 01h then
    magic = message[1- 16]
    if magic == "Protocol 1, GCM:" then
        gcmDecrypt(message, 17)
    else
        ecbDecrypt(message, 0)
// --- include other versions here ---
else
    ecbDecrypt(message, 0)
```

Of course this is still a very basic protocol. But at least you can change it later on. You might want to look at more complete protocol specs, such as Fernet, CMS or - of course - TLS instead of just AES-GCM.

Whatever you do: write down your protocol in a separate document and *refer to it from your code*. You may quote your simple protocol in the source code as easy lookup.

Comment: Of course the pseudo code an be improved using tables, switch statements, configurable protocols, variable fields set to the version number that is processed and so on and so forth.

Comment: This sounds a reasonable way. I also implemented a prototype to verify this idea. I have additional 2 questions: is there any risk without providing a `versionByte`? Is there any risk without using `tag` in GCM?

Comment: It is possible to leave out the version byte and encode it in the wrong yes, but it would make it harder for the follow-up protocol (s). Beware to test random things very well; edge cases may hurt you the millionth time. Use a different key for AES-GCM. The authentication tag is integral part of GCM, the result of GMAC so I'm not sure you know what you're asking here.